# How can i open default Files app with myapp folder programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, directory, swiftui

I have folder with files in my app. How can i open default Files app with myapp folder programmatically?

This is similar folder of GarageBand App in Files.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can open `Files` app in specific folder using `shareddocuments:` URL scheme and providing file path.

---

### Example:

```swift
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL { // returns your application folder
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}

let path = getDocumentsDirectory().absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "shareddocuments://")
let url = URL(string: path)!

UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

---

### P.S:

For more information, read [this article](https://www.macstories.net/ios/fs-bookmarks-a-shortcut-to-reopen-files-and-folders-directly-in-the-files-app/).

Comment: This is not what is being asked here. OP is asking how to make his app to show as the initial directory.

Comment: @LeoDabus *How can i open default Files app with myapp folder programmatically?* May be I've got it wrong, but I was sure that there is a question about how to open Files app in some given directory.

Comment: there is a property `directoryURL` that can be set to define the starting directory but I have never succeeded  using it. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller/3183918-directoryurl

Comment: @LeoDabus Hm, I gonna wait for OP to respond. I will remove the answer if it doesn't relate. Just wanna help :)

Comment: I want to open Files app (as other application), without selecting dialog

Comment: I know about replace "file" with "shareddocuments")))

Comment: @alexbayker I hope it helped you :)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Just adding this here if anyone is using this approach. You will need to enable showing your app folder. The link will show you how to **enable showing your app folder with downloaded files**. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63481939/how-to-download-a-pdf-file-in-swift-from-a-url-and-where-to-find-the-file-in-fi

Comment: Is it possible to open this within the App?

Comment: @unobatbayar you can use ur own views and access files using FileManager. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721418/getting-list-of-files-in-documents-folder

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; `documentPicker.directoryURL = <#your folder directory#>`

You need to use a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` and a `Coordinator` Class. The Class can be nested inside your Struct. The present it where required with a `.sheet()`

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct DocumentPicker : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
    
  class Coordinator : NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
        
        func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
            
            //the function gives an array of urls for the selected file.
            //chances are only going to be one
            guard let url = urls.first else { return }
            
            /*
             when trying to access resources outside our apps sandbox its important
             to call startAccessingSecurityScopedResource(). Then stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource().
             Once we have finished.
             */
            let secureAccess = url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
            
            //handle your file however needed for your app
            //   .... your action ......
            if secureAccess {  url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }
        }
    }
    
    //These are required to me implemented. Though one we just can leave empty
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
        let documentPicker =  UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [<#UTTypes#>], asCopy: true)
            documentPicker.directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! //<-- This opens Files App to your Apps Documents Folder
            documentPicker.delegate = context.coordinator
     return documentPicker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController, context: Context) {
        //can be left empty but the function must exists
    }
}
```